# libgdx camera combined coordinate system

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

In the `render()` method I've set my camera to `camera.combined`, but now I've noticed that everything is reversed. My sprites are reversed. How can I flip the camera or something?

```
public void render() {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
}
```

Comment: would you provide some code, notice you may on camera constructing added flip to true. and are you using Perspective?

Comment: i saw this exacty same question a week or two ago on here.. do some searching it will turn up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your yDown

```
cam.setToOrtho(yDown, viewportWidth, viewportHeight)
```

set `yDown = true`